# How to use "group by grouping sets" and "having" with total line?

Tags: monetdb

I created this SQL command:

```
select
    product_category_name a,
    count(product_id) b
from
    sys.odeds_2_20210811095253
group by
    grouping sets ((product_category_name), ())
```

The result is this:

```
a            b     
-------------------
Eletrônico   74    
Escritório   70    
Fruta        310   
Limpeza      37    
Utensílio    69    
Ferramenta   39    
Laticínio    32    
Bebida       72    
Móvel        27    
Grãos        53    
Higiene      57    
Informática  64    
Farmácia     26    
Verdura      23    
Vestuário    23    
Brinquedo    13    
Veículo      11    
<null>       1000
```

Is correct.
But, now I would like to make filters on groups.
Then I changed the command to look like this:

```
select
    product_category_name a,
    count(product_id) b
from
    sys.odeds_2_20210811095253
group by
    grouping sets ((product_category_name), ())
having
    grouping(product_category_name) = 1 or count(product_id) between 40 and 60
```

The result is this:

```
a        b     
---------------
Grãos    53    
Higiene  57    
<null>   1000
```

But, the result of the last line was not as I expected.
I would like the last line to return "110" (which corresponds to 53 + 57) instead of "1000".

Could someone help me solve this challenge?

Answer (score 0):

The having clause is filtering on the grouping sets, so I think that query won't do the job. You can the following query instead. I added one more subquery because I don't like to use the having clause, so it gets one less optimization step on the common expression elimination ;)

```
with totals(a, b) as
(
select a, b from
(
select
    product_category_name a,
    count(product_id) b
from
    sys.odeds_2_20210811095253
group by
    product_category_name
) sub(a, b)
where b between 40 and 60
)
select a, b from totals
union all
select null, sum(b) from totals;
```